# GCM Integration for Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Even though i did all the instruction in Google developers page for Gcm (Manifest Settings , Configuration File , Register in Console..)

```
 public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

public MyInstanceIDListenerService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels
        subscribeTopics(token);

        // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
        // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
        // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

/**
 * Persist registration to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}

/**
 * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
 *
 * @param token GCM token
 * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
 */
// [START subscribe_topics]
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
// [END subscribe_topics]
```

}

The gcm_defaultSenderId and QuickStartPreferences cannot resolve. Why ?? How can i overcome it ??

Answer (score 1):

`gcm_defaultSenderId` is a string you must create. It is your app sender ID.

`QuickStartPreferences` serves as an example. It is a class you may create to hold preference keys, if you want to remember that the token has been sent to your server (see comment above this line).

Comment: ok for QuickStart Preference i just want to be sure , but one of the aim of configuration file is create gcm_defaultSenderId , right ?

Comment: ah, yes maybe, I don't use it, I use a Java constant to store my sender ID. Did you enable the plugin in your gradle file?

Comment: yes i enabled it , i did all the configuration for several times in several projects. I understand i must miss something but i cannot find it.

Comment: R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId will be created automatically by gradle if you put google-services.json file in it's right place (app/google-services.json) and make sure about gradle version and dependency and plugin.